# Uniqueness of left/ right inverse for a nonsquare matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have an $m\times n$ $(m\ne n)$  matrix $A$, and if I find an $n\times m$ matrix $B$ such that $AB = I_m$, is it necessary that $B$ is unique? If so,how I prove it?

Answer (score 2):

It is not unique.

Counter example for right inverse:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -1 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -1 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} 2\\1\end{array}\right)=(1).$$

Counter example for left inverse:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\-1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 1 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\-1\end{array}\right)=(1).$$